# Soften edges on an image after MagickFloodfillPaintImage is applied

Tags: ios, imagemagick

I'm trying to remove the background of an UIImage and ended up using iOS port of MagicWand.

I was able to successfully remove the selected pixels using the flood fill algorithm by invoking the method MagickFloodfillPaintImage. However the challenge now is softening the sharp edges left by the Flood fill removal process.

I'm using the code below to remove the background.

```
PixelIterator* iterator = NULL;
    PixelWand** pixels = NULL;
    size_t x;
    iterator = NewPixelRegionIterator(magick_wand, _touchCoords.x*scale, _touchCoords.y*scale, 1, 1);
    pixels = PixelGetNextIteratorRow(iterator,&x);
    bc_wand = pixels[0];

    channel = ParseChannelOption("rgba");
    status = MagickFloodfillPaintImage(magick_wand, channel, fc_wand, _tolerance, bc_wand, _touchCoords.x*scale, _touchCoords.y*scale, MagickFalse);
    if (status == MagickFalse) {
        ThrowWandException(magick_wand);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need anti-aliasing in `MagickFloodfillPaintImage`. However `MagickFloodfillPaintImage` do not support it.

But fortunately, you can use traditional multisampling technique to simulate it.
And it is quite easy:

1. Resize your image to a larger resolution (For example 100x100 -> 200x200)(Up sampling).
2. Apply MagickFloodfillPaintImage
3. Resize the image to the original size (Down sampling).

The quality depends on the resize ratio.

Consider this example (remove the white background):

[image: before]

Original algorithm would produce hard edges:

[image: after1]

With resize, it could be much better:

[image]

Comment: Tried the approach you said but the result is not quite good. Are there any other iOS libraries or tools that I can use to remove the background? I tried OpenCV and it does a good job except that I have this problem which I have stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637657/opencv-floodfill-replace-pixel-color-with-transparent-pixel