# OpenCV Floodfill - Replace pixel color with transparent pixel

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm trying to do Floodfill on UIImage and ended up using OpenCV framework. I can replace the color with a solid color by defining the color as cv::Scalar(255,0,0). However I want the floodfill selection to be transparent.

I don't know how I can define a transparent color in OpenCV and to the best of my knowledge it's not possible and the only option is to merge the image to a transparent background. Again it doesn't make much sense to Floodfill using a solid color and then merge it with a transparent layer as the result will be the original image with solid color in the fill areas.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Much appreciate your help in solving this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a transparent color in OpenCV since it currently do not support image with alpha channel.

However, there exists a tricky solution. You may first refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574937/opencv-floodfill-onto-new-mat) to create a mask of your floodfill area. Then you can easily calculate the alpha channel from this mask.